# Is there an advantage to normalizing labels when using MSE loss?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, mse, gradient

I am designing a NN that uses MSE as a loss regressor. Its a big network and when I train, the loss/gradients are **HUGE**. I have to clip my gradients our else the loss just goes to NaNs. The differences in my targets vs labels can be in the 100,000s, which can cause 1e12 valued losses to be backpropogated through the network.

Is there an advantage to normalizing my labels to a certain range so that I do not need to clip the gradients? Again, to get even reasonable training from my network I have to max clip the gradients at some point, and then I move to clipping sum of the gradients to an arbitrary normalized number

e.g. `clip_grad_norm_()` in Pytorch: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/utils/clip_grad.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've answered your question: yes, it is a good idea, and standard practice, to normalize labels.

Comment: Could you provide some reference for this statement? Where this "standard practice" is described?